# extract an id from a tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-content-extraction, siebel

I have an automatically generated A tag in Siebel application like given below

```
<a href='JavaScript:SWESubmitForm(document.SWEForm2_0,s_5,"s_2_2_16_0","1-DOOYAL")'  tabindex=2997  id='s_2_2_16_0_efl''>
```

I need to extract the following value "1-DOOYAL" from this tag. I am not able to construct the jquery expression to do the same.

Can anybody please help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var split = $(this).prop('href').split('","');

return split[split.length - 1].substr(-2);
```

Comment: Don't you want `.attr("href")`?

Comment: sorry, I am a newbie it might be stupid question but don't I need to select the a tag based on id and then perform this operation?

Comment: @Phrogz: Maybe. That code is out of context, so I'll just edit it in to be sure.

Comment: @user1017268: That's up to you. I'm not sure how you're selecting these tags.

Answer (score 1):

Assumes that it is always double-quoted, comes at the end, and does not have commas or parens in the value.

```
var href = $("#s_2_2_16_0_efl").attr("href");
var v = href.split(/[",\)]+/);
var dooyal = v[v.length-2];
```